# Forcing order with time format on Excel

Tags: excel, plot, excel-formula, excel-2010

I run a test overnight and have the results written on a txt file that I later extract the time and value from. The result is something like this:

[Time data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7EO2.png)

Because it goes overnight and the time resets, the resulting plot is this:

[Out of order plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbDMq.png)

Is there any way to force the order in which the values are plotted without modifying the original .txt file so that it looks like my daytime tests?

[in order plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmKIo.png)

Edit:
Indeed the actual data skips and the timestamps are not periodic, here's how it looks around midnight

[Not periodic timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDzF6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a helper column and you need to make sure your time is actual excel time, and not a time string.  Assuming your time is in column B starting in cell B2 you can use the following process:

1)  Test cell

```
=ISNUMBER(B2)
```

If that is TRUE then you know you have your time stored in excel format.  In excel time is stores as a decimal which represents the portion of a day.  12 noon is 0.5.  Dates are stored as integers and represent number of days since 1900/01/01 with that date being day 1.

2)  Add 24 hour increment

In order to properly sort your order for graphing purposes, you will need to add a day everytime your data passes the 24 / midnight mark.  Assuming your data is sorted chronologically as per your example, use the following formulas in lets say column C

```
First cell C2
=B2

In C3 and copy down
=IF(B2>B3, B3+1,B3)
which can be rewritten as
=B3+(B2>B3)
```

Now format the cells in C for time.  The date will not display, only time will. The times after the 23:59:59 mark will all be the following day.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what i needed.
Just had to tinker with the format to make it look good on the plot for later usage.

Comment: Nice catch, Really good work Forward Ed.
@RafaelM., don't forget to mark Forward Ed post as accepted, grey mark under the voting buttons [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It shows other people that the question is solved and give Forward Ed the credit he deserves :)!!